# Find Next Word In A String

Tags: c++, string, find, cpu-word

I am trying to do work on individual words in a string. I read mulitworded string and want to keep track of it using string::size_type's hopefully the code is pretty self explanatory.

Right now I can't think of a way to advance p1 to the start of the next word after the first loop.
I'm stuck in an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static string NextWord(string &S, string::size_type &p1, string::size_type &p2)
{
    static char delimiters[] = " \n\t";
    string re = "none";

    p1 = S.find_first_of(S, p1);
    p2 = S.find_first_of(delimiters, p1);
    re = S.substr(p1, (p2 - p1));

    if (p1 == string::npos)
        return string("");

    return re;
}

int main() {
    string word, test = "I like pie and men are cool but what????";
    string::size_type   p1 = 0,
                        p2 = 0;

    while (p1 != string::npos)
    {
        word = NextWord(test, p1, p2);

        if (p1 == string::npos) {
            break;
        }

        cout << word << endl;
        p1 = p2;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fwiw word-extraction from a string is already provided by the standard library: [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: You can split a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) into "words" in a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). In fact it's just three lines of code (of which two lines are declarations).

Comment: Example of what Joachim was referring: [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/IjkVEP)

Comment: That's great! The larger program integrated the size_types in some other ways now and then so I couldn't ditch them. Thanks for the extra example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two comments already tell how to do it with the std library. But with your code set p1 to the next non-delimiter in each pass of NextWord.

```
static string NextWord(string &S, string::size_type &p1, string::size_type &p2)
{
    static char delimiters[] = " \n\t";
    string re;

    p1 = S.find_first_not_of(delimiters, p1)
    if (p1 == string::npos) 
        return "";
    p2 = S.find_first_of(delimiters, p1);
    re = S.substr(p1, (p2 - p1));

    return re;
}
```

Comment: lol, of course. I'm just sitting here staring at code trying to figure out the obvious. Thanks so much.